# Problem with Figure counter in the 0th chapter in book class

Tags: floats, chapters, book-class

I have a 0th chapter in my book to recollect the prerequisites. The figure environment is supposed to follow the default numbering scheme: `\thechapter.\thefigure`. However, this scheme is violated in the 0th chapter, whereas the behaviour is as expected in the 'non-zero' chapters. The following MWE illustrates the problem. I want the `figure`s to follow the same numbering scheme in the 0th chapter as in other chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{0th}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Image A}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{figure}
    \chapter{1st}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Image A}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the tag `\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}` from the package `amsmath` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{0th}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Image A}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{figure}
\clearpage
    \chapter{1st}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Image A}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Originally `book.cls` defines `\thefigure` as:

```
\renewcommand \thefigure
 {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
```

which means, that the chapter counter is only shown, if the chapter number (`\c@chapter`) is greater than 0 (`\z@`). This is, to avoid e.g. the usage of the chapter counter prefix for chapters in the frontmatter.

To avoid this, you could remove the condition and use:

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

in the document preamble. The same could be done using:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}% only to have the counter only once in the reset list of chapter, which usually wouldn't be problematic
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
```

But (as already explained), this would also show, e.g., "0.<FigureNo>" in the front matter, where the chapter won't be numbered. To avoid this, you can use a definition similar to the KOMA-Script class `scrbook`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\if@mainmatter\thechapter.\fi\@arabic\c@figure}
\makeatother
```

If you also have other elements also using the chapter counter in your chapter 0, you can adapt all the above also for those. For example for tables replace `\thefigure` by `\thetable`, `figure` by `table` or `\c@figure` by `\c@table`.

Here an example with all relevant counters, defined by `book.cls`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
%\renewcommand*{\thelstlisting}{\thechapter.\arabic{lstlisting}}% if you use listings in your chapter 0
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{0th}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Image A}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{figure}
\clearpage
    \chapter{1st}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Image A}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```